# Shutdown part of socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor, shutdown, fdopen

Given `FILE* stream = fdopen(sfd,"r+")`, where `sfd` refers to the file descriptor of a socket, is there any function that takes a `FILE*` as parameter and is able to shutdown a part of the socket (ie, close the socket for write processes)?

Or, alternatively: Is it safe to use `shutdown` (as described in shutdown(3)) (preceeded by an invocation of `fflush()` of course), when I already invoked fdopen on the socket file descriptor? I wasn't able to find the answer in the man pages (nor on the internet).

Thanks.

Comment: `shutdown(fileno(stream), ...);`

Comment: @user207421 which is basically the same as `shutdown(sfd,...)`. My question is, if it is legit to invoke `shutdown()` on the file descriptor, since there exists already an associated stream? Could the invocation of `shutdown()` result in undefined behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: Not 'basically the same'. *Exactly* the same. But that's what you asked for. The answer to the rest is also 'yes', but yes you need to `fflush()` first.

Comment: Alright, thank you!